# 3 or 2 column dynamic layout on CSS, unexplained empty spaces

Tags: layout, css-selectors

For some reason there's a strange empty space between the last two images. I have tried to clear left/ right, swop images around, change the (nth child). I don't know why this space appears. My URL is suzannereeve.com

Please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your responsive.css line 31 you have **#gallery li:nth-child(4n).**
Change that to **#gallery li:nth-child(3n+1)**

Your probleme was that you made it to be a multiply of 4 (so 4 elements in a row instead of 3).

Comment: Thanks! That works when the screen is wider than 66opx. It still has some strange blank gaps for smaller screens. Any idea what I should do there?

Comment: You should put the whole list in another div and give to that container a width of 87%~90%; after that remove from responsive.css the line 31 things, and make sure you have **#gallery li {float:left;}** This should make it work in every cases.